# Updating multiple rows in sql and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table , that needs to update specific rows.The user ticks(using checkbox) which value to update and this is then sent as an array (the two values) This value(s) then needs to be changed in the database.The problem is it updates both values with the same. i need both values to be different based on whats coming in from the post array

I am not sure if i should use a join? or a for loop?

How do you go about updating multiple values coming in  from a checkbox array? . All i want is for it to update both values based on the POST array values.The correct values are coming in from post array as i used var_dump

```
foreach($_POST['course_id'] as $course_id) {

    $update_query = "UPDATE course_student SET course_id='$course_id' WHERE student_id='$student_id' ORDER BY course_id";
    $update_course_result = mysqli_query($connection,$update_query);

    if($update_course_result && mysqli_affected_rows($connection)>0) {
        echo "Success";
        // more code here
    }

}
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to ask???

Comment: can you post the html form too? i think it might make it clearer what you're trying to do. also an update statement doesn't have an order by clause

Comment: And please take care about SQL Injections...

Comment: Why do you `ORDER BY` and `UPDATE` query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to delete all the entries for the student first and re-insert the newly checked values afterwards:

```
DELETE FROM course_student WHERE student_id='$student_id'
```

And then in your foreach-loop execute the following query:

```
INSERT INTO course_student SET course_id='$course_id', student_id='$student_id'
```

This looks afterwards like an "update" because you removed everything (also the not checked ones). And inserted all new checked entries.

And please take care of SQL-injections as mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: thanks man , i was doing some reading and came across this , will test it out now.

Comment: problem is that when i do this, it never gets reinserted again , its gone. Also do the checkboxes have to be sticky for this to work?

Comment: @LukeSmith What do you mean by "sticky"?

Comment: if someone checks checkbox and they click submit and there an error the value is still there.

Comment: this is my foreach loop that comes after delete query -     foreach($_POST['course_id'] as $course_id){

    $query_update="INSERT INTO course_student SET course_id='$course_id',student_id='$student_id'";

Comment: Of course do the checkboxes have to be "sticky". Every form should be sticky due to usability.

Comment: yes but does it possibly affect the code? also do you think the loop is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Maybe a SQL error?

Comment: it just deletes does not update. Could this be because i have a parent table and this table is set to cascade on update

Comment: Probably or you maybe have an SQL error you don't catch and handle?

Comment: this parent table make sure this course table exist when a student registers.now i only want to update the data in this course table but i think the parent table is holding me back from updating. is there anything i can do?As when i do this delete it wont reinsert. No sql error

Comment: i am inserting more than one value at a time